# connecting to the loop back (10.0.2.2) on an android / xamarin / VS2015 emulator setup

Tags: android, xamarin, proxy, visual-studio-2015, emulation

this old story again.

I cannot get my emulator to speak with my local windows development machine. I know that I need to use 10.0.2.2 as the IP to connect to 127.0.0.1 on my development machine. I have had the thing working one week ago but since then, several reboot and some tinkering later it will not connect.

As simple as putting 10.0.2.2 in the browser (on the emulator) fails. I can connect to the public internet fine in the browser. the BBC and Google work.

It's not a firewall issue as the response is not "actively refused" and I turned it off to no avail.

I am not systems expert and have little interest in systems stuff but I suspect there is "proxy" stuff involved. I have removed the proxy settings which were on my windows machine. I use fiddler a lot and I understand that it affects proxy settings ??

Where do I go now. I fire up an emulator using VS 2015 and it works fine. I can use the browser for public sites. I cannot connect to 10.0.2.2. It just times out.

How do I proceed please clever people?

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to use fiddler as reverse proxy which makes it easier to access localhost from Android easier: [Use Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy)

After that you will be able to connect to localhost:8888 and fiddler will redirect request to your local server.

Comment: (struggling with return characters!!)

Hi, I followed the instructions in the the link and allowed remote connections. I added the reg settings but I cannot connect still.

I am putting in the browser on the android emulator all the combinations I can think of. Ultimately I want to connect to port 5151 so I have tried:

http://localhost/
http://localhost:8888/
http://10.0.2.2/
http://10.0.2.2:8888/
http://127.0.0.1/
http://127.0.0.1:8888/

Comment: @DavrosSpignot: Did you update fiddlerscript? http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy#write-a-fiddlerscript-rule

Comment: I am a little confused by the link above. There seems to be three things to do? I did them all and added the following line to the fiddler script and in a browser on my windows machine "webserver:8888" renders the 127.0.0.1 response of the default IIS landing page, so that is working

`code`if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "webserver:8888") oSession.host = "127.0.0.1:80";`code`

I still cannot get the emulator to respond to 10.0.2.2. What IP should I be using in the emulator. The penny has not dropped for me yet on this one. I really appreciate the advice.

Comment: @DavrosSpignot: You should use webserver:8888 in emulator too

Comment: I get a name resolution failure message from the browser and also from a web request I am making in my app. I definitely had this working with 10.0.2.2 last week connecting to a WCF program on a specific port. 

I feel like I am not revealing some important piece of information some how.

Comment: @DavrosSpignot: Try using local ip address if your computer instead of webserver, something like 192.168.0.1:888